# Xubuntu does not recognize Epson WF-2540 All-In-One

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, printing, xfce

I have struggled with this problem for quite some time but cannot get Xubuntu  16.04 LTS to work with this device (Epson WF-2540 All-In-One).

Xubuntu is loaded on a Dell 1525n laptop (2008 vintage) that has worked with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 in the recent past but have had *no joy* with 16.04.

Attempting to let the system find the correct printer driver has thus far not 
installed the correct driver which, according to Epson, is 201211w.

I am perplexed.  I have never encountered this problem in the past with Ubuntu.  I could regress and install Ubuntu 16.04 but was hoping to get to work with Xfce.

Comment: Did you install `lsb`? Xfce has nothing to do with printer drivers.

Comment: I did not install _lsb_ and after reviewing the lsb Wikipedia, it appears that it does not apply to Xubuntu 16.04.  However, I could be missing something.

Comment: I have no problems with lsb on 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc are ALL the same Ubuntu-core. If it works on one, it should work on any of them.

Alternatively, you can download specific drivers for your 'all-in-one' from Epson webpage. Download the deb files for your platform (x86, x64, etc) and install by opening them with (Gnome) Software.